# Installing Ubuntu on external USB 3 SSD disk?

Tags: boot, usb, hard-drive, ssd

I am planning on buying an external USB 3 SSD disk and then install Ubuntu on that.

Anyone has experience with the drop in performance compared to installing it on internal SSD drives?

I also read some experience problems with even getting it to run on a USB 3 external drive, but is that still an issue for Ubuntu 16.x and forward?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? I have run full installs on USB2 & USB3 flash drives with both BIOS & UEFI. Flash drive is a lot slower than SSD, but limiting writes made them functional. But USB port becomes speed limiter unless newer 3.1 SuperSpeed. And trim is not supported on USB ports, so you need a SSD that internally handles trim itself.

Comment: Ok nothing what you wrote made any sense to me